# Convert array from one structure to another

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Maybe this is not good place to ask such question, but anyway:
I have an array with this structure:

```
let array = [["1", "value 1"], ["1", "value 2"], ["1", "value 3"], ["2", "value 4"], ["2", "value 5"]]
```

I need to convert this structure to this:

```
[["1", ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"], ["2", ["value 4", "value 5"]]]
```

I can't figure out how to do this, so if you help me it will be nice ) Thanks!

Comment: I would first parse your data out of this nested array data structure

Answer (score 0):

Explore the `reduce` operator on the array. :) This allows you to iterate over your array.

Then you simply need to check for the element's index 0 to know which category or key it falls under, then append there. You can then compose your result as a `Dictionary` which could be of type `[String: String]`.

Comment: Thanks you. I will try

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in imperative way:

```
var indexesArray: [String] = []
var valuesArray: [String] = []

for item in array {
    indexesArray.append(item[0])
    valuesArray.append(item[1])
}

let indexSet = Set(indexesArray).sorted()

for index in indexSet {
    var values: [String] = []
    var newArray: [Any] = []
    for (itemIndex, item) in indexesArray.enumerated() {
        if item == index {
            values.append(valuesArray[itemIndex])
        }
    }
    newArray.append(index)
    newArray.append(values)
    print(newArray)
}
```

Output in console looks like this:

```
["1", ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]]
["2", ["value 4", "value 5"]]
```

If someone has another more better, elegant solution feel free to post your code here, I will appreciate it!